# series involving Meijer $G$ function

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I'm trying to compute the sum:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^k}{k!}G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(c \  \Bigg\vert \  {k+1,0\atop k,a,b} \right),
$$
where $G$ denotes the Meijer $G$ function. I've tried

```
Sum[t^k/Factorial[k]*MeijerG[{{}, {0, k + 1}}, {{k, a, b}, {}}, x], {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

but it didn't produce anything useful.

Comment: You could try substituting specific values for a, b and t. If Mathematica can't evaluate these you are unlikely to get anywhere with the more general case.

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Yes, both a real, between 0 and 1 (not inclusive).